# Two apps with prod, dev, test environments, Best practice in Firebase console?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have two apps: user and manager. 
each of them has 3 different environments : production, development, test

How can this be setup in firebase console

What is the best practice to create projects in firebase console?

have 6 different firebase projects
or have 3 projects : production project which has two apps: user and manager, same for test and development

Answer (score 1):

I recommend separate environments: production, development, test into 3 firebase projects for data safety.

About user and manager app, It's depend on how it's data relation. Anyway, I think it should on 1 firebase project for easy to manage data and make analytics for your app.